# Is there some kind of "and" statement in Java?

Tags: java, boolean

I have a question which I would like to be answered. I am in the making of a app which needs to use booleans.
This is my code so far

```
if (but1 = true){
    //Do Something
}
```

But I would like to use a some type of `and` function in so I can say something like

```
if (but1 = true and but2 = true){
    //Do Something      
}
```

I have declared all my Boolean variables and would like to know if there is any type of function which will allow me to support this type of code which I need.
Thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried it? That would be faster than asking here.

Comment: read about [operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) and you will learn this and much more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is :

```
if (but1 && but2){
    //Do Something      
}
```

Just simple Java.

Comment: Yes but how would I say if but1 and but2 were equaled to true or false

Comment: Then you could use `!but1` (identical to `but1==false` or `but1!=true` but more readable). Also `but1` is identical to `but1==true` and `but1!=false`. It very basic logic : "but1 is true" if and only if "but1 equals to true"...

Answer (score 2):

I think that should be written this way:

```
if (but1) {
    //Do Something      
}

if (but1 && but2){
        //Do Something      
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Logical and is `&`. `&&` will shortcut the evaluation if the first parameter is false. Example:

```
// foo() and bar() will be called
if (foo() & bar()) {
}

// bar() will not be called if foo() returns false
if (foo() && bar()) {
}
```

Comment: `&` can also be used on `boolean`s. Check the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2).

Comment: I do agree that the result is the same for booleans. What I was contesting is the term **logical and**. The JLS link @martijno posted gives me reason and I quote: _'When both operands of a &, ^, or | operator are of type boolean or Boolean, then the type of the **bitwise operator** expression is boolean'_. You can check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this question has been been well answered, but just to make you aware:

```
if (but1 = true){
    //Do Something
}
```

will **always** evaluate as true as it takes the new value assigned to `but1`

Also using the '==' operator is unnecessary for booleans.

Answer (score 0):

&& is also a short circuit operator. If the first evaluation fails the second is not checked. You can use one & which check both parts of the statement.

For example

```
if (a() && b()){...}
```

Will not evaluate b() if a() is false. If you had one & then b() is evaluated even if a() is false

This is the same for or (¦  and ¦¦)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot compare variables with `=`.  A single equals sign is used for assignment, where `==` is used for comparison.

In Java, you can do the following:

```
if (a == true && b == true)
{
//do code
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
if (but1 == true && but2 == true) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: It's correct, but not idiomatic.  There's no need for the '== true'